# Modify/Update Simulink Block Name with Matlab

Tags: matlab, rename, block, simulink

I would like to know if i can modify/update the name of a Simulink block with the function set_param and if yes which param name i have to put or another function.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Lucas, your question might be sufficient already, but it might be helpful to others if you provide a code example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for example:

```
set_param('mymodel/Gain','Name','My custom name')
```

See the [documentation on `set_param`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/set_param.html) for more details.

Comment: Ok i have tested that yesterday it didn't work but today it works i don't know why but thanks !